# Take Element Screenshot @ Selenium 3

Tags: selenium

Here is written that a WebDriver should be able to take a screenshot of an element:

http://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#take-element-screenshot

(if your screen doesn't scroll down - please go down on the left panel to "19.2 Take Element Screenshot").

Does someone know how do code it in Java / Selenium please?

Answer (score 0):

For elements, I think you can adapt the C# solution

[How can I get screenshot of specified element using WebDriver in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35921168/how-can-i-get-screenshot-of-specified-element-using-webdriver-in-c-sharp)

otherwise for screens:

With `getScreenshotAs`

```
File sourcFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

FileUtils.copyFile(sourcFile, new File("/var/my_screen.jpg"));
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'd like to take a screenshot of an element, not the entire screen. Regards Joe

Comment: I edited my post, hopefully the link will show some similarities between C# and Java