# C# Selenium Web Driver is grabbing the wrong element location, but is getting the correct height and width?

Tags: c#, css, selenium-webdriver, xpath, system.drawing

I am trying to take a screenshot of a webpage I have accessed using selenium web driver.

I then want to crop the screenshot to only return a specific element. This happens to be an image.

I cannot grab the image file by the location, since re-requesting the same src will generate a different file.

I am unable to specify the image height and width as this will be dynamic.

Using the following code, I am able to successfully return the image height and width, however the screenshot that is saved is not the image, but another part of the page with the same dimensions as the image, which leads me to believe the location must be wrong?

Here's the code:

```
IWebElement image = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='hipTemplateContainer']/div[1]/img"));
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}",image.Location.X, image.Location.Y, image.Size.Width, image.Size.Height);
        TakeScreenshot(driver, image);

private static void TakeScreenshot(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement element)
    {
        try
        {
            string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss") + ".jpg";
            Byte[] byteArray = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot().AsByteArray;
            System.Drawing.Bitmap screenshot = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray));
            System.Drawing.Rectangle croppedImage = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(element.Location.X, element.Location.Y, element.Size.Width, element.Size.Height);
            screenshot = screenshot.Clone(croppedImage, screenshot.PixelFormat);
            screenshot.Save(String.Format(@"C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Images\" + fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace + ' ' + e.Message);
        }
```

I have tried to wait for the page to finish loading, that made no difference.

I have tried to get the parent element, but that also returned the wrong sizing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get screenshot of specified element using WebDriver in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35921168/how-can-i-get-screenshot-of-specified-element-using-webdriver-in-c-sharp)

Comment: This is slightly different, I am able to select the image to crop, I am getting an incorrect location however.

Comment: Use the exact code from the dup and see if that works. If it doesn't, you'll have to do some more debugging. It sounds like you are setting the rectangle incorrectly somehow.

Comment: So I tested the code on another machine, my original, and it worked fine. Do you know what my issue could be on my machine?

Comment: No idea. You would have to confirm that you've got everything the same... same Selenium, etc. versions, same code, and so on.

Comment: Yes, all identical. I actually built the application and just ran the exe. Works on one and not the other.

Comment: Are you doing things like maximizing the browser to further ensure that everything is the same? Have you updated the browser on both machines to the same version, etc.?

Comment: Yes, browser is maximised. Same exe ran on both PCs. Correctly captures on one and not the other. I even tried to use a Firefox driver and downloaded firefox and still had the same issue. I don't have the first clue what to do to find what's bugged.

Comment: I managed to find a fix, but it is not ideal. It seems that because my resolution is 1920 x 1080, my scaling by default was 125%. Upon setting this to 100%, it cropped as expected. Is there a better way to fix this than to change to 100% every time I wish to use the tool?

Comment: Not sure but I've heard that a non-standard zoom commonly causes issues.